# Binary to decimal, error message

Tags: java, for-loop, binary, decimal

I wrote a program that convert a binary number to decimal number.
When I run the program with some binary number, the program give me the decimal number but with an error message.

my code:

```
public class ohad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String bin = "10011";
        int length = bin.length();
        int j = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        if (length != 0) {
                    for (int i=0; i < bin.length(); i++){
                        if (bin.charAt(i) == '0' || bin.charAt(i) == '1'){

                            for (int t = (length - 1); t >= 0; t--){
                                String s = bin.charAt(j) + "";
                                sum = (int)(sum + (Integer.valueOf(s)) * (Math.pow(2, t)));
                                j++;
                            }
                            System.out.println(sum);
                        }                           
                        else {
                            System.out.println("illegal input.");  
                        }

                    }
        } else {
            System.out.println("illegal input.");

        }   

    }

}
```

error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at ohad.main(ohad.java:15)
```

I think it's something with my j index. What should I do?

Comment: Your J value is always changing in every inner loop. It is not a local variable within inner loop, it is shared by all this logic. So your loop will increase this all the time (it will getting more bigger than your index is). You should reset it after each inner loop :)

Answer (score 2):

*What should I do?*

I would use [`Integer.parseInt(String,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) like

```
String bin = "10011";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(bin, 2));
```

Output is

19

Answer (score 1):

Do you need j index? Looking at this quickly, I think you can use i index instead j.

```
String s = bin.charAt(j) + "";
String s = bin.charAt(i) + "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your j variable.

in the second iteration of the i for loop that is `for (int i=0; i < bin.length(); i++){`
j goes out of bounds as it is not set to zero again try the following code :

```
for (int i=0; i < bin.length(); i++){
    j=0; // add this 
    if (bin.charAt(i) == '0' || bin.charAt(i) == '1'){
        for (int t = (length - 1); t >= 0; t--){
             String s = bin.charAt(j) + "";
             sum = (int)(sum + (Integer.valueOf(s)) * (Math.pow(2, t)));
             j++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    } else {
        System.out.println("illegal input.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Elliott's answer is absolutely correct and gives a much easier way of solving the problem of converting a binary number to its decimal equivalent, it does not tell you what is causing the error.

You are correct that the exception is thrown because of the `j` variable, the issue lies in that the `j` variable is never set back to `0` when the inner loop (with index variable `t`). I changed your code to reflect this:

    `for (int t = (length - 1); t >= 0; t--){
        String s = bin.charAt(j) + "";
        sum = (int)(sum + (Integer.valueOf(s)) * (Math.pow(2, t)));
        j++;
    }
    j = 0; //this is the added code
    System.out.println(sum);`

This prevents the exception being thrown however causes another issue with the loop being called again, printing each time until you hit `95`. I'll let you fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've got one loop too much. That's why j keeps increasing causing the error message.
Delete the t loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bin = "10011";
    int length = bin.length();
    int j = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    if (length != 0) {
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (bin.charAt(i) == '0' || bin.charAt(i) == '1') {
                String s = bin.charAt(j) + "";
                sum = (int) (sum + (Integer.valueOf(s)) * (Math.pow(2, i)));
                j++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("illegal input.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    } else {
        System.out.println("illegal input.");

    }
}
```